# Link to external Bazel dependency

Tags: bazel

## Problem

I'm trying to modify [this tutorial](https://github.com/yukiB/tf-keras-speed-test) for compiling a TensorFlow network for use with C++. It currently requires you to copy your network file into the TensorFlow source code so the dependencies can be found, but I'd rather not do that. Note that TensorFlow is also built with Bazel.

Here is my `BUILD` file:

```
cc_binary(
    name = "mnistpredict_keras",
    srcs = ["mnist_keras.cc", "MNIST.h"],
    deps = [
        "//tensorflow/core:tensorflow",
    ],
)
```

When I try to run `$ bazel build :mnistpredict_keras` I get the error:

```
ERROR: /home/saubin/git/tf-keras-speed-test/loadgraph/BUILD:17:1: no such package 'tensorflow/core': BUILD file not found on package path and referenced by '//:mnistpredict_keras'.
ERROR: Analysis of target '//:mnistpredict_keras' failed; build aborted.
INFO: Elapsed time: 0.105s
```

Obviously, the problem is I'm trying to compile something in my folder `~/git/tf-keras-speed-test/loadgraph` but it can't find the dependency `//tensorflow/core:tensorflow`. How do I properly give the path to the dependency? The documentation for [`deps`](https://bazel.build/versions/master/docs/build-ref.html#deps) appears to be non-existent.

## Attempted Solutions

---

Adding a `local_repository` to my `WORKSPACE`:

```
local_repository(
    name = "tensorflow",
    path = "/home/saubin/src/tensorflow",
)
```

This changed nothing.

---

Trying to pass the full path:

```
cc_binary(
    name = "mnistpredict_keras",
    srcs = ["mnist_keras.cc", "MNIST.h"],
    deps = [
        "/home/saubin/src/tensorflow/tensorflow/core:tensorflow",
    ],
)
```

But I get the same error:

```
ERROR: /home/saubin/git/tf-keras-speed-test/loadgraph/BUILD:17:1: no such package 'tensorflow/core': BUILD file not found on package path and referenced by '//:mnistpredict_keras'.
ERROR: Analysis of target '//:mnistpredict_keras' failed; build aborted.
INFO: Elapsed time: 0.287s
```

---

Mark TensorFlow as an [external repository dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44147576):

```
cc_binary(
    name = "mnistpredict_keras",
    srcs = ["mnist_keras.cc", "MNIST.h"],
    deps = [
        "@tensorflow//tensorflow/core:tensorflow",
    ],
)
```

But this gives me this error:

```
WARNING: /home/saubin/.cache/bazel/_bazel_saubin/74f664e7cf53364557da8b57a716c919/external/tensorflow/WORKSPACE:1: Workspace name in /home/saubin/.cache/bazel/_bazel_saubin/74f664e7cf53364557da8b57a716c919/external/tensorflow/WORKSPACE (@org_tensorflow) does not match the name given in the repository's definition (@tensorflow); this will cause a build error in future versions.
ERROR: /home/saubin/git/tensorgraph/loadgraph/BUILD:1:1: error loading package '@tensorflow//tensorflow/core': Encountered error while reading extension file 'sycl/build_defs.bzl': no such package '@local_config_sycl//sycl': error loading package 'external': The repository named 'local_config_sycl' could not be resolved and referenced by '//:mnistpredict'.
ERROR: Analysis of target '//:mnistpredict' failed; build aborted.
INFO: Elapsed time: 0.326s
```

Answer (score 2):

The documentation for external dependencies is https://bazel.build/versions/master/docs/external.html.

The syntax that you are looking for is `@tensorflow//tensorflow/core:tensorflow`.

Labels that start with `//` refer to the *current* repository. Labels that start with `@reponame//` refer to the *reponame* repository.

Comment: This is probably right, but I'm still getting an error that might be TensorFlow specific. See the updated post.

Comment: The error message tells you what is wrong:

The repository named 'local_config_sycl' could not be resolved and referenced by '//:mnistpredict'

This is because bazel does not transitively load workspaces. Your workspace has a dependency on the tensorflow workspace, but the tensorflow workspace has its own dependencies on other workspaces. Namely, @local_config_sycl//. Tensorflow defines this workspace here: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/workspace.bzl#L141 which is called from https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/WORKSPACE#L17.

Comment: so I should import all the external's deps of tensorflow in the workspace?

Comment: If you are attempting to reference tensorflow as an external repository, then yes. Please open a separate StackOverflow question if you run into more issues.